# invoke a SOAP service. Error 404 filter is unavailable

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am calling a soap service from a java function, when i call the service, it gives an error : 
`HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found [Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8, $WSEP: , Content-Language: en-US, Content-Length: 97, Connection: Close, Date: Tue, 12 May 2015 05:21:40 GMT, Server: WebSphere Application Server/7.0]`

here is my code :

```
            public String callWebService(String serviceURL, String Request) {
              String strresponse = "";
            try {
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(serviceURL);
            StringEntity stringentity = new StringEntity(Request);
            stringentity.setChunked(true);
            httppost.setEntity(stringentity);
            httppost.setEntity((HttpEntity) stringentity);
            httppost.addHeader("Accept", "text/xml");
            httppost.addHeader("SOAPAction", "");
            httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
            httppost.setHeader("METHOD", "POST");
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            strresponse = null;
            if (entity != null) {
            strresponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            return strresponse;
            }
```

the raw response is mentioned above.

the response from `strresponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);` is : `Error 404: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [CRMInboundWSDLFilter]: filter is unavailable.`

any thing i am doing wrong ?

the request i am calling is working on the same URL using a webservice Studio client.

Comment: Is your HTTP method correct?  Are you also using a POST when you make the call from the Studio client?

Comment: yeah http method is correct. yes i am making the request using https://webservicestudio.codeplex.com/

Comment: You should be capturing the HTTP requests using both way of calling (code and webservicestudio) and compare them, there should be some difference (can be around url).

Comment: You're setting SOAPAction as empty? Your SOAPAction is really empty?

Comment: I think there is some problem with header parameters. Maybe you can have TCP/IP monitor between your service and webservice Studio client. Find all the headers. And make it available in your HttpPost header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was using the WSDL end Point as the URL, that is why it wasn't calling the service. i checked it by entering the URL being generated by the studio then i called it. it was successful.